# error in qemu monitor wavcapture with virsh

Tags: permissions, linux-kvm, qemu

I have VM running on qemu-kvm. I am managing it with libvirt and command line tool virsh.

I want to record the audio output of the VM. Here is what I am trying -

> virsh qemu-monitor-command -hmp VM_NAME wavcapture VM.wav

This is the output I am getting :

```
Failed to open wave file `vm.wav'
Reason: Permission denied
Failed to add wave capture
```

I have tried to create a dummy vm.wav with 777 permissions. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I guess I'll need to answer my own question. So as it turns out, libvirt uses apparmor for security of VMs. So the VM doesn't have r/w access to many locations. 
To use wavcapture, we need to provide access to the VM through apparmor rules. 
Straightforward way of doing this is to edit /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu
and add your rule. Then stop and start VM, and reload apparmor.